# Mocha before() does not listen to event emitter from Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am learning to implement Mocha tests for my Node Express application, but running into issues with my tests executing before my server had finished processing some code. Essentially, I want my server to emit an event after loading that tells my Mocha framework it's okay to begin running the tests.

So in my `app.js` file, I've emitted an event:

```
let app = express();
app.use(require('./controllers'))    
var port = 8080
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    logger.info('Server started on port ' + port + '.');
    httpServer.emit("serverStarted");
    logger.info('Emitted action.')
});

module.exports.httpServer = httpServer;
```

In my `artworks.tests.js` file, I have a `before()` function that only calls `done()` after the server is ready to begin test:

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let logger = require('../util/logger');
let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const artworksController = require('../controllers/artworks');
var server = require('../app').httpServer;

    before(function (done) {
        server.on("serverStarted", function(){
            logger.info("Event listened to.")
            done();
        });
    });
```

However, my Mocha tests continue to fail on the `before` hook:

> mocha **/artworks.test.js -t 10000

```
2018-04-15T01:35:00.709Z - info: Server started on port 8080.
2018-04-15T01:35:00.713Z - info: Emitted action.
2018-04-15T01:35:00.982Z - info: Connection to mongodb successful! The application is now connected to MONGO_DB_URL
  1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (10s)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.As you can see, I've set the timeout to 10 seconds, plenty of time for the server to boot up. However, clearly, the `server` in my `artworks.tests.js` file is not listening to events being emitted. I expect that the `before()` function's `done()` after the server is started, and then I can begin performing my other tests.
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://mrvautin.com/ensure-express-app-started-before-tests/), which other SO posts have referenced as being extremely helpful in ensuring that tests run only after the server has finished booting up.

Comment: I think your server is emitting the event before your `before` function executes. you could try moving this: `var server = require('../app').httpServer;` into your `before` hook.

Comment: @MikeAtkins thanks. This was exactly the issue. I'm not sure if you care about points and whatnot, but go ahead and write this up as an answer and I'll accept it.